# Requests Testing - Sending unconventional requests

Tags: python-requests

I have an automation project which includes Requests Testing .
Some of the test cases requires sending a request "methods" that are not the regular known ones (e.g. GET,POST...). For example, one requires sending chars like "SSS" instead of a request method and see how this goes via wire-shark. Is there a way to do this using Python? is it possible to do this via requests module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the `requests` module comes with the chance to do unconventional requests.

However, you can still use **sockets** to connect to a remote host and send whatever you want. For instance:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 
s.connect(("foo.com", 80))
s.sendall("SSS / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
r = s.recv(4096)
print r
s.close
```

Comment: I have tried your method but i get an error that says : "TypeError: connect() takes exactly one argument (2 given)" is possible i should ditch the "80" ?

Comment: I think I was missing parenthesis when invoking ```connect```.

Comment: Thank you! it is working now, will implement it in my tests